Am I doing the t-test on wind vectors correctly?
I'm trying to create an wind anomaly plot and shade the regions that are statistically significant at the 95% level using the Student's t-test.
The anomaly plot is simple to do. The problem is that my current code for the t-test seems...wrong.
x1 = t_ds['wind'].mean(axis=0)
x2 = ds['wind'].mean(axis=0)
s1 = t_ds['wind'].std(axis=0)
s2 = ds['wind'].std(axis=0)
n1 = 21
n2 = 186

t_ds['t'] = abs(x1-x2)/(((s1**2)/n1)+((s2**2)/n2)**0.5)

That is my current code. The second line is simply the formula for the Studen't t-test.
t_ds is the sample years while ds is all the years
The 'wind' parameters are just:
t_ds['wind'] = ((t_ds['u']**2) + (t_ds['v']**2))**1/2
ds['wind'] = ((mean_ds['u']**2) + (mean_ds['v']**2))**1/2

The critical t-value in my case is 1.984 so any t-value above 1.984 will be shaded in the map. But I'm not sure if what's being shaded is correct.

The large wind anomalies aren't shaded while the smaller wind anomalies are. This doesn't seem right but I may be mistaken.

Interesting question, but since it's mostly conceptual, I think you'll find a more suitable audience at [stats.SE]. That said, I'm not sure a significance test such as a t-test is appropriate here. I can't tell from the code you posted exactly what you're trying to do -- you may want to try to clarify your goals if you post again at [stats.SE] -- but anyway bear in mind that you'll get a "signficant" result if your samples are large enough, since you know a priori that there is temporal evolution and spatial variation.

My advice is to look for a practical difference -- this is essentially the motivation behind "effect size analysis". A web search for that term will find some resources.
